# Proving that R is an Equivalence Relation.

Tags: relations, equivalence-relations

> Consider the relations R and S on $\Bbb N$ defined by $x\; R\; y$ iff
>
> $2  \;$divides $x + y$
> and $x \;S \;y$  iff $3$ divides $x + y.$

$\text{QN: Prove that $R$ is an equivalence Relation }$

So my question for this one is that I understand how one is able to prove that it is reflexive and symmetric. But I am struggling to figure out how to prove that it is transitive. I cannot seem to grasp that concept.

$x+y = 2a \Rightarrow x+y = 3a$

$(i)$ $xRx$ , then $2$ divides $x+x = 2x$, therefore reflexive.

$(ii)$ If $xRy$ $2$ divides $x+y$, $2$ divides  $y+x$ ,$yRx$. Thus Symmetric.

Comment: Do you mean $2$ divides $y+x$ in (ii)?

Comment: It is worth mentioning that $R$ will indeed be an equivalence relation, but $S$ will not.  For you to think about: why isn't $S$ an equivalence relation?  Which property or properties will fail for $S$?

Comment: I made that a separate question as it would be unfair to ask two questions for one problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For transitivity, like so:

$xRy$, so $2$ divides $x+y$

$yRz$, so $2$ divides $y+z$

Now add the two together, you know that $2$ has to divide the sum, so $2$ divides $x + y + y + z = x + z + 2y$.

But since $2 | 2y$ and $2 | (x + z + 2y)$ then $2$ must divide $x + z$, hence $xRz$.

Comment: How come you have to two y's but only one x?

Comment: Because, if $2$ divides $a$ and $2$ divides $b$, then $2$ divides $a + b$. Here $a = x + y$ and $b = y + z$, so $a + b = x + y + y + z = x + 2y + z$. The intuitive way to think about this is that we know that $x$ is connected to $y$, and $y$ is connected to $z$. We want to show that $x$ is connected to $z$ via the connection of $y,$ which is why the 'boundary' $y$ has a different role, i.e: there are two $y$'s and one $x$.